# Cutting a Midi file

Tags: windows-vista, audio

I want to edit a midi file so to cut it to a specific length.
Any good and simple freeware for doing this?

I'm running Windows (Vista)

Comment: Sorry, Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://cellphoneforums.net/ringtones/t115899-midi-faq-how-make-edit-midi.html

This is talking about some different midi editors out there.  I think most of the tools will be for windows.
http://www.anvilstudio.com/ This is one free one mentioned for windows.